# Node.js static header for all requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, http-headers

I want to set a static header for all incoming request in my node.js server.
My current way is to add for each request the same 4 lines of header(code duplication) and i want to fix that, here is one example of the header i want to add :

```
app.post('/postJob', function(req,res){
    console.log("request method :" + req.method);
    // Website you wish to allow to connect
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

    // Request methods you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

    // Request headers you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

    // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
    // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

Someone knows a way to define that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like so

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    next();
});
```